# convert a string to pdf in react

Tags: reactjs, string, raw-data, react-pdf

In a react app, I am getting a raw pdf string from an API and I would like to convert it to a pdf document in a new tab in the user browser.

I fetch the data with a simple `Axios` request and get something like this in return:

```
data: "JVBERi0xLjcKNyAwIG9iago8......."
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
headers: {
cache-control: "no-cache, must-revalidate"
content-length: "361614"
content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
expires: "0"}.....
```

any suggestions on how to convert this raw string to a pdf file in react?

Comment: `JVBERi0xLjcKNyAwIG9iago8...` is a base64 encoding of `%PDF-1.7 ...` - you'll have to decode the base64 encoding to get at the binary PDF.